# NestedRuntimeException: Cannot parse POST parameters of request

Tags: java, jsp, exception, post

As part of an application, we have a JSP page (parent page) in which we are calling another JSP page (child page), where all the parameters of the child page has been assigned to the form of the parent page and then trying to submit the page.

At the time of submission, we are getting the following error on the frontend...

> ```
> (I) Front end error
> =====================
> Error 500--Internal Server Error
> From RFC 2068 Hypertext Transfer Protocol -- HTTP/1.1:
> ```

And on the backend we get the following error...

```
    (II) Application server Error log

     <Error> <HTTP> <BEA-101019> <[ServletContext(id=29607640,name=test,c
    ontext-path=/Test)] Servlet failed with IOException
    java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out
            at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method)
            at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:129)
            at weblogic.servlet.internal.PostInputStream.read(PostInputStream.java:170)
            at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletInputStreamImpl$1.read(ServletInputStreamImpl.java:115)
            at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletInputStreamImpl.read(ServletInputStreamImpl.java:180)
            at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletRequestImpl.mergePostParams(ServletRequestImpl.java:1339
    )
            at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletRequestImpl.parseQueryParams(ServletRequestImpl.java:120
    6)
            at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletRequestImpl.getParameter(ServletRequestImpl.java:1409)
            at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.invokeServlet(ServletStubImpl.java:446)
            at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.invokeServlet(ServletStubImpl.java:348)
            at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext$ServletInvocationAction.run(WebAppServletC
    ontext.java:7047)
            at weblogic.security.acl.internal.AuthenticatedSubject.doAs(AuthenticatedSubject.java:321)
            at weblogic.security.service.SecurityManager.runAs(SecurityManager.java:121)
            at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.invokeServlet(WebAppServletContext.java:39
    02)
            at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletRequestImpl.execute(ServletRequestImpl.java:2773)
            at weblogic.kernel.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:224)
            at weblogic.kernel.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:183)
    **--------------- nested within: ------------------
    weblogic.utils.NestedRuntimeException: Cannot parse POST parameters of request: '/Test/test1.jsp
    ' - with nested exception:
    [java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out]** 

            at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletRequestImpl.mergePostParams(ServletRequestImpl.java:1364
    )
            at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletRequestImpl.parseQueryParams(ServletRequestImpl.java:120
    6)
            at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletRequestImpl.getParameter(ServletRequestImpl.java:1409)
            at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.invokeServlet(ServletStubImpl.java:446)
            at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.invokeServlet(ServletStubImpl.java:348)
            at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext$ServletInvocationAction.run(WebAppServletC
    ontext.java:7047)
            at weblogic.security.acl.internal.AuthenticatedSubject.doAs(AuthenticatedSubject.java:321)
            at weblogic.security.service.SecurityManager.runAs(SecurityManager.java:121)
            at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.invokeServlet(WebAppServletContext.java:39
    02)
            at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletRequestImpl.execute(ServletRequestImpl.java:2773)
            at weblogic.kernel.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:224)
            at weblogic.kernel.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:183)
```

Could you please offer a suggestion as to the cause of the problem.

Comment: If your question has been answered, or if it is no longer valid, please 'tick' to choose the most appropriate answer so everyone knows that the problem has been resolved. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You are getting a SocketTimeoutException, so there is probably something wrong with your POST. For example, you might not be sending through enough bytes of data, or you might not be closing off the connection once you're finished with it - basically its sitting there waiting for more information until it eventually times out.

Could you please post some of your JSP code, especially where you're creating and running your POST, so that we can provide some better feedback.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the quick reply. Its very legacy code I didn't really understand  what excatly i need to put over here as lot of bits and pieces are here and there.   I am confused.But I understood the prblem is due to bytes of data. Can you please tell me if suppose I declare StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer(50) and while appending to the stringbuffer if it exceeds the specified size and while posting as post parameter will have any problem like this .

Comment: No this probably wont be causing a problem. However, why are you using a StringBuffer? If you are trying to send a String through the POST, you will need to use something like StringWriter instead, which will output a value to a stream. If you are sending the StringBuffer through the POST, it would probably be better to send a plain String instead - sending a StringBuffer through POST probably wont do what you expect. Could you please post some code if you would like further assistance, so we can better answer your question.

Comment: Actually they are appending to StringBuffer and later applying toString(). It sometimes working sometimes not , I really didnt understand what part of the code needs to be pasted here as the code is in bits and pieces which really confusing me.I am doing a bug fix , Actually how they are doing is there is A.jsp where they are embedding B.jsp , the form tag is B.jsp where they are doing some checkbox selections and submitting the form where it will be routed to A.jsp and from there to B.jsp .   Form they are making <form METHOD="post" NAME="BasicEdit" ACTION="<%=strPAGE_URL%>">

Comment: The same code works in another Weblogic server (test environment) but the same is not working in one environemnt(Development). Will there any Configuration level issues that related to Weblogic Configuration.Can you Please help us on this .. Thanks in Advance